# Color text FUNCTION in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, colors

I am trying to make a function in bash that gets a parameter and based on that parameter it colors the text. Say colorText RED will color my text red. This is what I wrote so far but it says `./colorText: line 10: ${$1}dad: bad substitution`

```
#!/bin/bash

RED="\033[31m"
GREEN="\033[0;32m"
YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
NC="\033[0m"

colorText () {
echo $1
echo -e "${$1}dad"
}

colorText $1
```

The last $1 is because I want to use the script file from my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A c
c["RED"]='31'
c["GREEN"]='32'
c["YELLOW"]='33'
c["BLACK"]='0'

colorText () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
    printf '\e[%sm%s\e[0m\n' "${c[$1]}" 'dad'
}

colorText "$1"
```

See also:

1. [tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269077/tput-setaf-color-table-how-to-determine-color-codes)
2. [using-awk-to-color-the-output-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046525/1745001).

Answer (score 0):

So check if `$1` is equal to RED, if it is, output `$RED`, repeat for every color. You can just switch on the color number.

```
case "$1" in
RED) n=31; ;;
GREEN) n=32; ;;
YELLOW) n=33; ;;
esac
echo -e "\033[${n}m"
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple small tweaks to OP's current code:

```
colorText () {
    local -n color="${1}"           # define local variable as nameref
    echo -e "${color}dad${NC}"      # add ${NC} to turn off colorization
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
RED="\033[31m"
GREEN="\033[0;32m"
YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
NC="\033[0m"

colorText RED
colorText GREEN
colorText YELLOW
colorText BLUE                     # BLUE is undefined so there should be no color applied
```

This generates:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you already created color variables then just use them as is, like this:

```
RED="\033[31m"
GREEN="\033[0;32m"
YELLOW="\033[0;33m"
NC="\033[0m"

colorText(){ echo -e "${1}dad"; }

colorText "$RED"
```

IMHO function is redundant here, just use `echo -e` or `printf` with color vars:

```
printf "${RED}dad${NC}"
```

ps. check out [this](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color/blob/master/color)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple function that translates human-readable names into [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit), and `echo`es a string with that color:

```bash
function color() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 2 ] ; then
    echo "[ERROR] color <color-name> <text> expected two arguments, but got $#" >&2
    return 1
  fi

  local -r colorName="$1"
  local -r message="$2"
  
  local colorCode="0;37"
  case "${colorName,,}" in
    black          ) colorCode='0;30' ;;
    red            ) colorCode='0;31' ;;
    green          ) colorCode='0;32' ;;
    yellow         ) colorCode='0;33' ;;
    blue           ) colorCode='0;34' ;;
    magenta        ) colorCode='0;35' ;;
    cyan           ) colorCode='0;36' ;;
    white          ) colorCode='0;37' ;;
    bright_black   ) colorCode='0;90' ;;
    bright_red     ) colorCode='0;91' ;;
    bright_green   ) colorCode='0;92' ;;
    bright_yellow  ) colorCode='0;93' ;;
    bright_blue    ) colorCode='0;94' ;;
    bright_magenta ) colorCode='0;95' ;;
    bright_cyan    ) colorCode='0;96' ;;
    bright_white   ) colorCode='0;97' ;;
    gray           ) colorCode='0;90' ;;
    *              ) colorCode='0;37' ;;
  esac
 
  echo -e "\e[${colorCode}m${message}\e[0m"
}
```

Here are a few example inputs and outputs:

[image: example inputs and outputs]

Basic usage:

```bash
color red 'something went wrong'
color green 'all good'
```

produces:

[image: red and green messages]

It always appends the `RESET` after the colored string, so that the rest of the text is not messed up. Thus,

```bash
echo "$(color red '[ERROR]') There were $(color red '42 errors'), build failed."
```

will color only `[ERROR]` and `42`, and leave all the other text with default settings:

[image: a message where only error and '42' are colored red]

The `${   ,,}` converts the name of the color to lowercase, so it doesn't matter whether you write `red`, `RED` or `Red`.