# printf showing colour code instead of applying the colour in the second argument

Tags: linux, bash, colors, printf

I'm trying to apply a color into this printf trying to make it nice looking:

I'm building a script that shows a list of function names and their description of what it does.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Colours
greenColour="\e[0;32m\033[1m"
endColour="\033[0m\e[0m"
redColour="\e[0;31m\033[1m"

#Format the output in a table-like structure
printf "\n${greenColour}[+]${endColour} %-15s %s\n" "${redColour}getPIP${endColour}" "Shows private IP"
```

But when I execute the script the first argument ([+]) does get the colour applied but the second argument shows the color code instead of applying the other colour:

```
[+] \e[0;31m\033[1mgetPIP\033[0m\e[0m Shows private IP
```

Any ideas if this is doable somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Expected: Apply colour to the second argument passed to printf
Result: I see the colour code instead

Comment: Get rid of that space and the double quotes ... `%s\n" "`

Comment: When I do that the option %-15s does nothing, now it just looks like a normal echo. What I need from printf is the possiblity of giving it some margin in the description column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes are tricky in this case; a backslash doesn’t have the same meaning as in C’s double quotes… For example, this works for me:

```bash
greenColour=$'\033[01;32m'
endColour=$'\033[00m'
redColour=$'\033[01;31m'
printf "\n${greenColour}[+]${endColour} %-15s %s\n" \
       "${redColour}getPIP${endColour}" \
       "Shows private IP"
```

On my terminal, `[+]` is green and `getPIP` is red in this case. The codes used above are the “simplified” ones though, not the [full 24-bit True Color ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404415/353114).

Comment: When I executed the script like this its trying to execute this " "${redColour}getPIP${endColour}" " as a separated command so it throws "command not found"

Comment: Sorry, forgotten space after backslash. Fixed.

Comment: That actually fixed the whole issue, not only the space in the backslash, but the code of the colours now does apply the second colour. I knew nothing about the full 24-bit True Color ones.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's inconsistent to sometimes be using the colour in the printf formatting string and other times passing the colour with the printf argument. FWIW I'd separate the formatting/colours from the content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Colours
greenColour=$'\e[0;32m\033[1m'
endColour=$'\033[0m\e[0m'
redColour=$'\e[0;31m\033[1m'

fmtRed="\n${greenColour}[+]${endColour} ${redColour}%-15s${endColour} %s\n"

#Format the output in a table-like structure
printf "$fmtRed" 'getPIP' 'Shows private IP'
```

I'd also come up with a better name for the variable `fmtRed` based on **what** type of data will be printed using that format rather than **how** (i.e. what color) that data will be printed but I can't tell the "what" from your question.

Comment: Would you use tput setaf colours instead of color codes like this? I'm asking for a way to have more sharable usability between shells...

Comment: @SerBer definitely. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046525/1745001.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will bear this in mind.

Comment: If you are going to use escape sequences though then see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72966038/1745001.