# Read file by character to colorify but output by line

Tags: linux, bash

I made a script that uses the `shuf` command to pick from a list of colors, and then applies them randomly to the output line by line:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\n\n"
while IFS= read -r line; do echo -e "\e[38;5;$(shuf -n 1 shuf.ans)m${line}\e[0m";done<ty && echo ""
```

**shuf.ans** has the list of numbers that represent specific colors, and **ty** is some stylized text:

```
888888 88  88    db    88b 88 88  dP     Yb  dP  dP"Yb  88   88 d8b d8b d8b
  88   88  88   dPYb   88Yb88 88odP       YbdP  dP   Yb 88   88 Y8P Y8P Y8P
  88   888888  dP__Yb  88 Y88 88"Yb        8P   Yb   dP Y8   8P `"' `"' `"'
  88   88  88 dP""""Yb 88  Y8 88  Yb      dP     YbodP  `YbodP' (8) (8) (8)
```

The current output changes the color by each line, but I was trying to think of how to change the color of each character but output by line.  When I try to use `read -r -N1` or `-n1` it outputs each character on a separate line.

Current output is like this:

[image: ASCII art "THANK YOU!!!", each line a different color]

This is not very important but was trying to do it character by character or a few characters at a time but still output so that you can read the text.  I know there are things like figlet but those aren't always options depending on the distro etc.

Comment: Why do you need to "output by line"? If you read and write by character, you'll read the newline and write it to the output normally.

Comment: Re "I know there are things like figlet but those aren't always options depending on the distro": On what system isn't it a viable option? http://www.figlet.org/ gives a pretty comprehensive list.

Comment: FYI -- the more portable and reliable equivalent of `echo -e "..."` is `printf '%b\n' "..."`, or for `echo -en '...'`, `printf '%b' "..."`. See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) over at [unix.se].

Comment: Regarding "change the color of each character" - As you can see from the answers so far, different people have different understandings of "character", is it the whole "T" in "Thank You" or each of the 12 "8"s that make up the T individually? That's why it's important to add the expected output to any question, please [edit] your question to state what you mean by "character" and add some expected output (you could just copy/paste an image from whichever answer produces the output you want).

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

randintrange() {
    echo $(( ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) ) + $1 ))
}

printf '%s' "\n\n"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do 
        printf '%s' "$(tput setaf $(randintrange 1 7))${line:i:1}$(tput sgr0)"
    done
    echo
done < ./ty
```

[image]

---

Do NOT hardcode terminal escape sequences. Use `tput` with the sequence names from `man terminfo` to get the right code for your terminal. Eg. `red=$(tput setaf 1); echo "Hello ${red}world!"`

More info at http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/

---

To test all combinations:

```
#!/bin/bash

colors=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)

reset=$(tput sgr0)

for fg_color in ${colors[@]}; do
    for bg_color in ${colors[@]}; do
        fg=$(tput setaf $fg_color)
        bg=$(tput setab $bg_color)
        printf '%s' "${fg}${bg} fg=$fg_color:bg=:$bg_color${reset}"
    done
    echo
done
```

[image]

Comment: In my original post i did not include the contents of shuf.ans but it could be an array really, 
I did a script similar to what you suggest, thank you!  it is a bit slow since it's changing  color on every character as i had suggested, but it does work:    

`#!/bin/bash

colrange=(5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165)

printf '%b' "\n\n"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    for ((i=0; i<${#line}; i++)); do
        printf '%s' "$(tput setaf ${colrange[RANDOM%${#colrange[@]}]})${line:i:1}"
    done
    echo
done < ./ty`

Comment: apologies for the formatting, i'm not sure why adding a comment isn't the same as making a post i guess

Answer (score 2):

I'd use awk for improved speed of execution and portability:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numColors = split("BLACK RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN WHITE",tputColors)
    for (i in tputColors) {
        colorName = tputColors[i]
        colorNr = i-1

        cmd = "tput setaf " colorNr
        fgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
        close(cmd)
    }

    cmd = "tput sgr0"
    colorOff = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<sgr0>" )
    close(cmd)

    srand()
}
{
    numChars = length($0)
    out = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=numChars; i++ ) {
        char = substr($0,i,1)
        if ( char ~ /[[:graph:]]/ ) {
            color = tputColors[int(1+rand()*numColors)]
            char = fgEscSeq[color] char colorOff
        }
        out = out char
    }
    print out
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk ty
888888 88  88    db    88b 88 88  dP     Yb  dP  dP"Yb  88   88 d8b d8b d8b
  88   88  88   dPYb   88Yb88 88odP       YbdP  dP   Yb 88   88 Y8P Y8P Y8P
  88   888888  dP__Yb  88 Y88 88"Yb        8P   Yb   dP Y8   8P `"' `"' `"'
  88   88  88 dP""""Yb 88  Y8 88  Yb      dP     YbodP  `YbodP' (8) (8) (8)
```

[image]

Compare execution time to the currently posted shell answer:

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk ty >/dev/null

real    0m0.405s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.045s
```

```
$ time ./tst.sh ty >/dev/null

real    0m13.857s
user    0m0.135s
sys     0m0.152s
```

Note that when the color selected for a character is the same as the background color of your terminal the character obviously disappears. Unfortunately there is no portable way to determine the current background color of your terminal (see [how-to-determine-the-current-color-of-the-console-output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172548/how-to-determine-the-current-color-of-the-console-output) so you can't portably automatically exclude that color from the list of colors you choose from but you can pass in a color to the script and then skip that color. Just change this:

```
    colorName = tputColors[i]
    colorNr = i-1
```

to this:

```
    colorName = tputColors[i]
    if ( colorName == toupper(bg) ) {
        continue
    }
    colorNr = i-1
```

and then call the script as `awk -v bg=black -f tst.awk ty` and then it won't use black as one of the character colors:

[image]

Alternatively, if your terminal and version of `tput` support it, you may be able to use `system("tput sc")` at the start of the `BEGIN` section to save your current terminal colors at the start of the script, set a specific background color within the script with the help of adding this to the first loop to get the background color codes:

```
    cmd = "tput setab " colorNr
    bgEscSeq[colorName] = ( (cmd | getline escSeq) > 0 ? escSeq : "<" colorName ">" )
    close(cmd)
```

then `system("tput sc")` in an `END` section to restore it afterwards. See [recursive-pattern-search-output-formating-for-each-match-file-print-out-the-s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757396/recursive-pattern-search-output-formating-for-each-match-file-print-out-the-s/757435#757435) for an example where I do that part from shell outside of the call to awk.

See also the following answers to related questions:

1. [searching-and-coloring-lines-by-awk-or-other-method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669111/searching-and-coloring-lines-by-awk-or-other-method/669122#669122)
2. [calendar-highlight-in-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691669/calendar-highlight-in-unix/691810#691810)
3. [Using awk to color the output in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034385/using-awk-to-color-the-output-in-bash/64046525#64046525)
4. [recursive-pattern-search-output-formating-for-each-match-file-print-out-the-s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757396/recursive-pattern-search-output-formating-for-each-match-file-print-out-the-s/757435#757435)

Answer (score 1):

> but I was trying to think of how to change the color of each character

I may have misinterpreted the term "character", which I believed was referring to a "rendered character" (being `T` `H` `A` `N` `K` and so on), with each of which having a random color, while all the "terminal characters" (being the ones a rendering is made out of, namely `8` `d` `P` `"` `_` and so on) would have the same color inside a single rendered character. Either way, this awk script might also be of use for others.

The input rows are first analyzed character-by-character for all-blank columns (i.e. the ones containing only whitespace characters across all rows) by simply deleting their indices, if a given row is defecting from that rule, from an array that started out with all column indices included. Then, for all the indices remaining, a random color is generated, and consequently printed before the corresponding column is reached. As exceptions, the first column is never deleted from that empty-columns array, so the first rendered character also receives its coloring, while the column after the last one is also added to that array, and then forcefully bound to the (terminal-configured) default foreground color, in order to reset the coloring after the end of each (especially the last) line.

```
{
  while (w<length($0)) g[++w]; d[NR]=$0
  for (i=2; i<=length($0); i++) if (substr($0,i,1)!~/[[:space:]]/) delete g[i]
}
END {
  srand(); g[++w]
  for (i in g) {
    cmd="tput " (i==w? "sgr0": "setaf " int(rand()*8))
    cmd | getline col; g[i] = col; close(cmd)
  }

  for (i=1; i in d; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=length(d[i])+1; j++)
      printf g[j] substr(d[i],j,1)
    printf "\n"
  }
}
```

[image: terminal output with each "rendered character" in a random color]

---

> how would i substitute your random numbers here for a random number within this array? colrange=(5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165)

Be aware that not all terminals support setting colors of higher value, so be cautious, and don't expect that on all other terminals it'll look the same: on one it might just show different colors (depending on the terminal's configuration), on others it might even not work at all.

That said, split a string of space-separated numbers into an array using `split("5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165", pal, " ")` (put it ideally in the `END` block, but before (the loop in which) `rand()` is applied), and replace the random color number generator with a random array index number generator by shifting the range from `0…7` (as per the `setaf` capabilities, see `man 5 terminfo`) in `rand()*8` to `1…16` (the valid array indices) in `rand()*16+1`. Use the generated index number by accessing the array at that position using `pal[…]`.

```
{
  while (w<length($0)) g[++w]; d[NR]=$0
  for (i=2; i<=length($0); i++) if (substr($0,i,1)!~/[[:space:]]/) delete g[i]
}
END {
  split("5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165", pal, " ")
  srand(); g[++w]
  for (i in g) {
    cmd="tput " (i==w? "sgr0": "setaf " pal[int(rand()*16+1)])
    cmd | getline col; g[i] = col; close(cmd)
  }

  for (i=1; i in d; i++) {
    for (j=1; j<=length(d[i])+1; j++)
      printf g[j] substr(d[i],j,1)
    printf "\n"
  }
}
```

[image: terminal output with each "rendered character" in a random color, using a predefined color palette]

Comment: You interpreted correctly as far as what I mean but I think this looks equally good, thank you!  awk is definitely faster but could you explain your work?  this is more of a learning tool for me and I'd like to mention a few things:  i never changed the background color in my original, just the text and assumed the background color is black, so i'm assuming that would simplify this!  i also was using a random selection of these specific colors:  5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165

Comment: I'm not setting the background color, so it's just the background as configured in the terminal (mine is almost black). If you want to actively set it, have a look at `tput setab` elsewhere on this page. But also the foreground colors, although explicitly set by the script, are dependent on your terminal's configuration, and may look different in another terminal (my theme is quite similar to the [gruvbox dark](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox#dark-mode-1) palette). As for the awk script, I tried to describe it in more general terms, but if you have specific questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: i mean i guess i would have to read the whole awk manual haha, but how would i substitute your random numbers here for a random number within this array?  colrange=(5 9 13 15 124 125 126 127 128 129 160 161 162 163 164 165)

Comment: I deliberately chose to only set colors in the range `0…7` (as per the `setaf` capabilities, see `man 5 terminfo`). Use higher values only if your terminal supports them, and don't expect that on all other terminals it'll look the same: it might show different colors (depending how the terminal is configured), or even not work at all. That said, to get a random value from that list, assign the 16 numbers to an array by `split`ting a prepared string, and replace the random color number generator with a random array index generator by shifting the range from `0…7` to `1…16`. See my edited post.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I'll have to spend more time with awk, I have in the past used it for very simple things like removing lines I don't want to see on an output etc